# Declaring Doctype HTML5

Tags: html

With HTML5, declaring the doctype only requires this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Where as older versions needed something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Why doesn't HTML5 doctype need to reference the version such as `<!DOCTYPE html5>`?

I understand the doctype is only needed to force standards rendering, but if HTML6 was released with new features, wouldn't HTML5 declarations need to reference the version?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970013/is-the-html5-doctype-the-last-one-we-will-see

Comment: Thanks, answered my question perfectly. Apologies for not searching thoroughly myself.

Comment: maybe you can take a look at this. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: these comments should be collected and posted to make them an answer to the question.